# Check if h1 or h2 exists on a page

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have this code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(60)
driver.get(link)

driver.add_cookie({'name' : 'access_token', 'value' : token})
driver.refresh()

time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_name('next').click()
time.sleep(5)
```

How can I check if a  or  tag element exists on the page ?
I tried it this way:

```
falha = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('h1')
sucesso = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('h2')

if falha.text == "Por segurança":
    print ("Retorno: " + element.text + "\nToken: " + token)

if sucesso.text == "Pronto":
    print("Retorno: " + element.text + "\nToken: " + token)

driver.close()
```

But my code simply so that if one of the elements do not exist.

Comment: What about using `driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('h1')`, this will return you a list. Then you can check if it is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html), the locate methods throw an exception if the specified element is not found.

> If no element has a matching name attribute, a NoSuchElementException
>   will be raised.

Therefore, if the existence of an element is not guaranteed, you will have to wrap it in a try block to prevent your script from getting terminated.

```
try:
    falha = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('h1')
except:
    falha = None

if falha is not None and falha.text == "Por segurança":
    print ("Retorno: " + element.text + "\nToken: " + token)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `driver.find_elements_by_tag_name()` method for that, which will return you a list of matched tag elements.

Then you can determine it is present or not by using its size. Try the below code :

```
elementsh1 = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('h1')
elementsh2 = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('h2')

if len(elementsh1) > 0 :
    print("=> h1 is present...")
    print(elementsh1[0].text)
else:
    print("=> h1 tags are not there...")

if len(elementsh2) > 0 :
    print("=> h2 is present...")
    print(elementsh2[0].text)
else:
    print("=> h2 tags are not there...")
```

I hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

If tag 'h1' is exists run try codes and if tag 'h2' is exists run except codes

```
try:
    element = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('h1')
    print ("Retorno: " + element.text + "\nToken: " + token)

except:
    element = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('h2')
    print("Retorno: " + element.text + "\nToken: " + token)
finally:
    driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

This code handle all error(s)

```
try:
    falha = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('h1')
    for ele in falha:
        if ele.text == "Por segurança":
            print("Retorno: " + element.text + "\nToken: " + token)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

try:
    sucesso = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('h2')
    for ele in sucesso:
        if ele.text == "Pronto":
            print("Retorno: " + element.text + "\nToken: " + token)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```